# Any fun way applying concepts at home

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

Looking for fun ways to apply math concepts and play around with them, specifically using trigonometry, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- Work on a construction project (maybe build a small storage shed or deck or something), where you can gain practice using trigonometry for calculating angles, lengths of wood to use, etc
- Learn to program computers. Specifically for trigonometry, check out game development and computer graphics. Even if you don't have any experience with computer programming or digital art, there are a lot of free, open-source graphics and game development libraries with free tutorials online. Programming physics in game and manipulating vector graphics will provide tons of opportunities to employ math skills, and you'll have a useful/marketable skill to show for it at the end.
- Learn about physics, and set up simple physics experiments at home. This can be done with everyday materials, and can be fun to do with kids as well. While studying physics, you'll be employing trigonometry right from the beginning.